# Replacing main.js with index.js, Error: ENOENT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm confused with why is this bot now functioning, I think it's as I don't have a "index.js" I use "main.js" How can I some how switch from "main.js" to "index.js"?

I'll add all the main codes that may help you spot an error :D

Here is the code in "main.js":

```js
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ disableMentions: 'everyone', partials: 
['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], ws: { intents: Intents.ALL } });


client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();

['command', 'event'].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});


client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Error:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:269
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/DwaCraft-Ticket-bot/index.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:195:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/runner/DwaCraft-Ticket-bot/index.js'
}
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1

```

Package.json:

```js
{
    "name": "ticket-bot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A simple ticket bot",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node main.js"
    },
    "author": "hamoodi",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "better": "^0.1.0",
        "cpu-stat": "^2.0.1",
        "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
        "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "os": "^0.1.2",
        "sourcebin_js": "0.0.3-ignore"
    }
}
```

Files:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FptiD.png

Comment: change main property in package json to main.js

Comment: It's: "main": "main.js",

Comment: could you please add package json and how to run your project?

Comment: Sure, One second.

Comment: Here you go, added.

Comment: how about folder structure ? is your main.js in root?

Comment: I'm using https://replit.com

Comment: I just added a photo of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As below link said you can Create a .replit file, and inside it put

run="node [file].js"

and replace [file] to main.

https://replit.com/talk/ask/Is-it-possible-to-changedeleted-indexjs/43264

Answer (score 1):

Change  the name file from `main.js` to `index.js` in "scripts" => "start" in `package.json` file and hit `npm start`. Remember to run the `script` from the `folder` where the main.js **file is located**, and **rename files**!

```
{
    "name": "ticket-bot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A simple ticket bot",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "hamoodi",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "better": "^0.1.0",
        "cpu-stat": "^2.0.1",
        "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
        "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "os": "^0.1.2",
        "sourcebin_js": "0.0.3-ignore"
    }
}
```